# Nested "do" and "add" Actions is possible?

Tags: php, functions, actions

I'm wondering

Questions were asked about more than one "`add_action`" and filter nested before and it was deemed possible.

Are nested cross actions added?

**Eg.**

```php
add_action('init', function(){
   do_action('initialized');
});
```

```php
function initialized(){
   // ...
}
```

**Second question**

Will a vicious circle occur like the following?

```php
function initialized(){
   do_action('init');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can nest actions.

Yes, your example will cause an infinite loop.